# When to start reading Bott-Tu?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology

I have been reading Tu's manifolds book to prepare for the Bott-Tu one. How much of the first book should get me started with the second? Also, are there other books which could serve as a quicker introduction to manifolds, at the same level?

Comment: This depends a lot on your knowledge and predisposition, and makes this rather off-topic. The most practical course of action is that you *start reading the book*, and judge by yourself. Nothing prevents your from reading the book from cover to cover once, just to see what you'll encounter. You can read it like a story first, so that when you choose to study from it, you don't feel in strange waters.

Comment: Do you mean Bott-Tu's "Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology". If yes, then see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621819/preparing-for-differential-forms-in-algebraic-topology